# How to compose react-navigation with relay classic

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, relay, react-relay

I want to use react-navigation with relay in my project.

The thing I did was:

```
<RootContainer>
  <MyApp>
    <StackNavigator>
  </MyApp>
</RootContainer>
```

And the navigator has screens of my app.

Say in MyApp (which is relay container) I `query viewer{}`

---

If my screens were also relay containers, I should pass `viewer` from MyApp to Navigator then to my screen, (I don't know how to pass props to navigator).

---

If my screens were React component but in them I render relay containers, I should pass those container a `viewer`  prop which I don't have in the react component :\

Thanks in advance.